# Are there any implementations of algorithms on hardware that are (nearly) optimal?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Consider the notion of optimal implementation as follows. Suppose we have some algorithm $A$ whose execution for some problem of size $N$ requires $T(N)$ operations (e.g. arithmetic operations). A library optimally implements this algorithm when it executes a routine for implementing the algorithm for a problem of size $N$ on a CPU (or some other hardware), the CPU performs exactly $T(N)$ operations. That is, algorithm A is optimally implemented on a CPU if the routine has exactly 0 overhead. More generally, one might say that it implements it nearly optimally if there is some small fraction of overhead.

When looking around for examples, I believe to have found only one analysis of a nearly optimally implemented algorithm (namely the Smith-Waterman algorithm on GPUs [here](http://www.hicomb.org/papers/HICOMB2009-10.pdf)). In this case, they find that the algorithm requires 11 operations per cell update, so a GPU that can perform X integer operations/second should be able to execute X/11 cell updates per second. They find that their routine gets 70% to the X/11 number and is therefore quite close to optimal.

I'm interested in having examples of other algorithms that have been shown to be near-optimally implemented on some hardware platform. Other pointers for how I can find relevant examples would also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  If you define $A$ to be the algorithm that is implemented on the CPU, then by definition it is an implementation of $A$ with zero overhead.  In any case, theoretical measures of "number of steps" are a poor predictor of overall running time if you care about the exact running time in practice and are seeking to highly optimize running time.

Comment: @D.W. The algorithm is not identical to the routine ran to execute the algorithm. The routine needs to interact with low-level hardware stuff, like memory, logic, etc. Thanks for the comment, I'll clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, there is no such concept. The "minimum" number of operations to achieve a given task is completely dependent on the instruction set of the particular CPU. And if you don't limit yourself to existing CPUs, many options remain for custom designs (FPGAs, ASICs...), where the minimum is not even always defined, as it can depend on some design decisions and additional criteria, as well as on the measurement unit.

It is for a similar reason that algorithm complexities are usually estimated to an arbitrary factor (the "hidden constant" in BigOh). So there are no studies on this topic, except in very narrow cases/private circles. (Should I add that researchers will more often be after - or claim -  optimal solutions rather than near-optimal ones.)